# How much of this fertilizer should I use on my Jade Plants?

Tags: fertilizer, jade

[image]

I have this fertilizer that is meant for house flowers as well as vegetables, I was planning one using it for my Jade Plants. How much should I give them? I have never fertilized my Jade Plants before.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between flowering houseplants and those which are grown for their foliage. Flowering plants need a different NPK, whereas foliage houseplants do better with either a balanced NPK (7-7-7) or one that has a higher nitrogen level. Baby bio is a houseplant food and that has an NPK of 10.6-4.4-1.7, which you can see is quite  different from the NPK shown on the bag in your image.  I wouldn't use the fertilizer you have on a jade plant at all.

For Crassula ovata (Jade plant) you need a water soluble, standard houseplant food (such as Baby Bio), diluted according to the directions, but it needs very little in a year - 2 or 3 applications spread out through the year is perfectly adequate. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/jade-plant/jade-plant-care.htm